# Seek to the end of file and go up one line

Tags: python, logging, tail, seek

Looking for some help navigating up one line in the following code.
I can't figure out a way to make it move one line up.

I have tried [1] and -1, but can't seem to move up one line.

Any help is appreciated. My google skills are failing me right now. I think I have been staring at the problem for too long.

```
 import csv
 import time
 import os
 import datetime as dt
 import sqlite3

def follow(thefile):

    #Seeks to the end of the file 
    thefile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)  
    
    #Starts an infinte loop
    while True:
        
        #reads the last line of the file
        line = thefile.readline()
        
        #sleep if the file hasn't been updated
        if not line: #sleep if the file hasn't been updated
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        # Once all lines are read this just returns ''
        # until the file changes and a new line appears
        yield line
```

The file I am following always prints a blank line at the end.

Example file I am tailing

```
 10:21:25 service Execution 
 10:22:25 anotherService Execution 
 "<Blank Line>"
```

Example File I am tailing updated

```
 10:21:25 service Execution 
 10:22:25 anotherService Execution 
 11:30:00 service execution
 "<Blank Line>"
```

The software I am reading the log file from writes to the blank line on the update.  When the software loops it skips that line because it scrolls to the bottom so I am missing that data. I want to start reading from one line up.

I want to read line      '11:30:00 service execution'

Currently, my code keeps reading the blank line.

Comment: It seems quite implausible that any real software would go through the trouble of writing an empty line only to then seek back and overwrite it. For one thing, logging functionality should be absolutely as simple and predictable as possible. My hunch is that you are inspecting the file using a tool which is fooling you somehow.

Comment: Have you simply tried to `thefile.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)` or `thefile.seek(-1, os.SEEK_CUR)` to get the last line before the end or the previous line of your current position?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you need to continue the while loop when there is Blank line, so just add:

```
if line == '"<Blank Line>"':
    continue
```

Comment: I think my communication skill was lacking. The software I am reading the log file from writes to the blank line on the update.  When the software loops it skips that line so I am missing that data. I want to start reading from one lineup.